# Why am I getting a linker error? (Function template)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, instantiation

I am getting LNK1120 error, and I am not sure why. I am trying to use a template for int and double, that returns the corresponding type.

This is my Numerical_Analysis_Functions.cpp file

```
#include "Numerical_Analysis_Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template double 
midpointRule<double>(double arr[], int);

template <typename T> double midpointRule(double arr[], int size)
{

    return 1.0;
}
```

This is my Numerical_Analysis_Functions.h file

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
extern T midpointRule(T arr[], int size);
```

This is my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Numerical_Analysis_Functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    midpointRule(arr, 4);


    cin.sync();
    cout << "End of Program.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the `Numerical_Analysis_Functions.cpp` file compile without errors? That's not a valid function declaration you have there.

Comment: As for your problem, I think it might have something to do with your way of specializing the function.